# Subsequent JSONP requests give status 404 despite GET status 200

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, jsonp, yelp

So I am able to make the first JSONP request to the yelp API work to return business data for me, but any subsequent requests I make lead to the callback for failure that logs a status code of 404. Yet when I pull up the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools I see that all the subsequent GET requests I made all have status 200 and I do see valid response data. How can that be when the callback for failure was called? How can I fix this? I'd like to be able to receive data more than once.

The following code in question is based off the answer to this other question [Yelp API and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716264/yelp-api-and-angularjs), the difference being the statements directly below the comments

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="oauth-signature.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="plunker">
    <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p><date-input name="info.name" message="info.message"></date-input></p>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="business in businesses">
                {{business.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        function randomString(length, chars) {
            var result = '';
            for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
            return result;
        }

        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
        app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyYelpAPI', function($scope, MyYelpAPI) {
            $scope.businesses = [];

            // first time for the callback gets executed
            MyYelpAPI.retrieveYelp('', function(data) {
                console.log('callback1');
                console.log('data');
                $scope.businesses = data.businesses;
            });

            // the second time for the callback doesn't get executed
            MyYelpAPI.retrieveYelp('', function(data) {
                console.log('callback2');
                $scope.businesses = data.businesses;
            });

        }]).factory("MyYelpAPI", function($http) {
            return {
                "retrieveYelp": function(name, callback) {
                    var method = 'GET';
                    var url = 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search';
                    var params = {
                            callback: 'angular.callbacks._0',
                            location: 'San+Francisco',
                            oauth_consumer_key: '', 
                            oauth_token: '', 
                            oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
                            oauth_timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
                            oauth_nonce: randomString(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
                            term: 'food'
                        };
                    var consumerSecret = '',
                    var tokenSecret = '',
                    var signature = oauthSignature.generate(method, url, params, consumerSecret, tokenSecret, { encodeSignature: false});
                    params['oauth_signature'] = signature;
                    $http.jsonp(url, {params: params})
                        .success(callback)
                        // second time fails
                        // data -> undefined; status -> 404
                        .error(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data, status); // why is this happening?
                        });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i thin u need to do like this
 $http.jsonp("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?callback=JSON_CALLBACK, params)
        .success(function() {
            //success 
        }).error(function(){ //failure })
;

Comment: Adding the callback query parameter to the url did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this :

```
$http.jsonp("api.yelp.com/v2/search?callback=JSON_CALLBACK", yourParams) 
.success(function() {
     //success callback
})
.error(function(){
     //error callback
}) ;
```