# Second jsonp http get request - using $q gives 404 error despite GET showing 200

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, yelp

I've found a couple of similar posts to this, but the answers (which boil down to putting `callback=JSONP_CALLBACK` into the get request) aren't working for me. Using that in the request generates an immediate **404** error, while using `callback=angular.callbacks._0` at least lets the first request return a successful response. The problem is that using the very same request function with the very same params a second time to refresh the data or get the next 20 objects, returns a **404** error even though the actual get returns a **200** and the data can be seen in chrome tools.

I'm, new to using $q deferred promises, so I'm hoping that the issue has something to do with that not allowing enough time for a response before executing the **reject**. I'm attaching the code, which involves the Yelp API as did the other couple of posts I found on this issue. The most closely related is: ([Subsequent JSONP requests give status 404 despite GET status 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477053/subsequent-jsonp-requests-give-status-404-despite-get-status-200)), but there's another which uses the same callback string I'm using ([Yelp API and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716264/yelp-api-and-angularjs)).

This particular project is for an ionic mobile app that gets coffee shops based on users geolocation.

Here's the code for the service (secret stuff removed):

```
var app = angular.module('caffeine.services', []);

app.service("YelpService", function ($q, $http, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicPopup) {
function randomString(length, chars) {
            var result = '';
            for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
            return result;
};
var method = 'GET';
var url = 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search';
var consumerSecret = ''; //Consumer Secret
var tokenSecret = ''; //Token Secret
var self = {
    'page': 1,
    'isLoading': false,
    'hasMore': true,
    'results': [],
     'ranStr': randomString(32, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
    'timeStamp':new Date().getTime(),
    'lat': 51.544440,
    'lon': -0.022974,
    'term': 'coffee',
    'oauthConKey': '', //Consumer Key
    'oauthToken': '', //Token
    'oauthSigMeth': 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'refresh': function () {
        self.page = 1;
        self.isLoading = false;
        self.hasMore = true;
        self.results = [];
        return self.load();
    },
    'next': function () {
        self.page += 1;
        return self.load();
    },
    'load': function () {
        self.isLoading = true;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
$cordovaGeolocation
.getCurrentPosition({timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy:false})
.then(function(position){
  self.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    self.lon = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log('latlong = '+self.lat+','+self.lon);
            var params = {
            callback: 'angular.callbacks._0',
            page: self.page,
             ll: self.lat+','+self.lon,
            term: self.term,
            oauth_consumer_key: self.oauthConKey, //Consumer Key
            oauth_token: self.oauthToken, //Token
            oauth_signature_method: self.oauthSigMeth,
            oauth_timestamp: self.timeStamp,
                //new Date().getTime(),
            oauth_nonce: self.ranStr
        };
        var signature = oauthSignature.generate(method, url, params, consumerSecret, tokenSecret, { encodeSignature: false});
         params['oauth_signature'] = signature;    
        console.log('url ='+url);
        console.log('params.ll = '+params.ll);
$http.jsonp(url, {params: params}).success(function (callback) {
                self.isLoading = false;
                console.log(callback.businesses);
        if (callback.businesses.length == 0) {
                    self.hasMore = false;
                } else {
                    angular.forEach(callback.businesses, function (business) {
                        self.results.push(business);
                    });
                }
                self.isLoading = false;
                deferred.resolve(callback.businesses);
            })
            .error( function (callback, status, headers, config) {
                self.isLoading = false;
console.error('data not received');
console.error('data: '+callback);
console.error('status: '+status);
console.error('headers:  '+headers);
console.error('congig: '+config);
                deferred.reject(callback);
            });  
}, function(err) {
    console.error('Error getting position');
    console.error(err);
    $ionicPopup.alert({
        'title': 'Please turn on geolocation',
        'template': 'It looks like you have geolocation turned off.    Please turn on geolocation in your app settings to use this app.'
    });
})
});


        return deferred.promise;

}
};    
self.load();

return self;
});
```

Comment: Could it be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700384/yelp-api-oauth-and-angular-with-jsonp-only-works-once/37772708#37772708 ?